# fadeToggle seems to make the hidden div jump up

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hello I have two divs that fadeToggle with a timer as follows

```
<div id="div1">Hello</div>
<div id="div2" style="display:none;">World</div>
```

Javascript to make it toggle

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    setInterval(ToggleDiv, 5000);
});
function ToggleDiv(){
    $('#div1').fadeToggle("slow");
    $('#div2').fadeToggle("slow");
}
```

Here is fiddle link http://jsfiddle.net/BnYat/

My issue is that the second div shows up before the first div is done toggle and then causes a jump up to the top.

If there a way to create a smooth transition from one div to the next without the jump effect happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple solution is to put both `div` elements in a single container, and position them absolutely:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="div1">Hello</div>
    <div id="div2" style="display:none;">World</div>
</div>
```

```css
#container div {
    position: absolute;
}
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/BnYat/1/)

---

Alternatively, you could fade one out completely then fade the next in in the callback:

```
setInterval(ToggleDiv, 5000);

function ToggleDiv(){
    $('#div1').fadeToggle("slow", function() {
        $('#div2').fadeToggle("slow");
    });
}
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/BnYat/3/)

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    setInterval(ToggleDiv, 5000);
});
function ToggleDiv(){
    $('#div1').fadeToggle("slow", function(){
        $('#div2').fadeToggle("slow");           

    });

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 setInterval(ToggleDiv, 5000);

 function ToggleDiv() {
     var div = "#" + $('div:visible').attr('id');
     var div2 = "#" + $('div:not(:visible)').attr('id');
     $(div).fadeToggle("slow", function () {
         $(div2).fadeToggle("slow");
     });
 }
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Alfie/BnYat/2/)

or

```
function ToggleDiv() {
    if ($('#div1').is(':visible')) {
        $('#div1').fadeToggle("slow", function () {
            $('#div2').fadeToggle("slow");
        });
    } else {
        $('#div2').fadeToggle("slow", function () {
            $('#div1').fadeToggle("slow");
        });
    }
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Alfie/BnYat/4/)

Answer (score 0):

just use animate

```
$( "#div1" ).animate({
    visibility:hidden
  }, 5000, function() {
    // Animation complete.
  });
$( "#div2" ).animate({
    visibility:visible
  }, 5000, function() {
    // Animation complete.
  });
```